# Save all but some fields of a struct to a file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, save, matlab-struct

I have a struct variable which is `parameters` with some other variables ex `foo1` ,`foo2`. `parameters`  has 20 fields. ex. `a,b,c,d,e ...`
I want to save only 18 fields. I don't want to save `parameters.a` and `parameters.b`. So I want to save `parameters` except the fields `a` and `b` and `foo1` and `foo2`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either remove the fields before saving it with `rmfield`.

```
tosave = rmfield(parameters, {'a', 'b'});
save(filename, '-struct', 'tosave');
```

or you could get a listing of all fields, remove the fields you don't want and then pass these to `save`. This has the added benefit of not having to make a copy of the `struct`.

```
% Get all fields of parameters
allfields = fieldnames(parameters);

% Remove the fields you don't want to keep
fields = allfields(~ismember(allfields, {'a', 'b'}));

% Now save the rest
save(filename, '-struct', 'parameters', fields{:});
```

Or as @excaza notes, you can craft a regular expression with the `-regexp` flag to exclude the variables you don't want.

Comment: Or a regex: `save(filename, '-struct', 'data', '-regexp', '[^ab]');` Probably more of a pain than `ismember` though.